# Scaling image using Bitmaptransform and draw it using CanvasControl in win2d gives blurred image

Tags: c#, uwp, win2d

This is what I have tried:

```
var decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(fileStream);
BitmapTransform bitmapTransform = new BitmapTransform();
bitmapTransform.ScaledHeight = 300;
bitmapTransform.ScaledWidth = 800;

var pixelProvider = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync(
                        BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
                        BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,
                        bitmapTransform,
                        ExifOrientationMode.IgnoreExifOrientation,
                        ColorManagementMode.DoNotColorManage);

byte[] by = pixelProvider.DetachPixelData();
CanvasBitmap cb = CanvasBitmap.CreateFromBytes(sender,by,800,300,Windows.Graphics.DirectX.DirectXPixelFormat.B8G8R8X8UIntNormalized);
```

What I have done in the `Draw` event of CanvasControl:

```
private  void Canvas_Draw(CanvasControl sender, CanvasDrawEventArgs args)
{
    args.DrawingSession.DrawImage(cb);
}
```

Due to scaling, the image gets blurred. How can I solve this issue? I need to change the width and height of image dynamically at run time, how can I do that?

My Original Image:
[image]

After Draw (Blured Image):
[image]

Comment: Are you scaling the image to make it larger, or make it smaller?

Comment: i need both larger and smaller?

Comment: OK, I'll split this into two questions then: When you make it larger, is it blurry? When you make it smaller, is it blurry? I'm sure you can also provide an example set of images too.

Comment: How blurry does it get? All scaling will introduce some amount of artifacts, especially if the image is pixel-exact, like text or other UI graphics.

Comment: @John , I had Provide Some Picture example.

Comment: @JonasH,I had Provide Some Picture Example

Comment: The problem is probably that you scale down the bitmap to 800x300 during decoding, and the scaling is probably using nearest neighbor scaling. And then scale it up to 1002x374, causing it to blur. Not sure how to solve, it, perhaps remove scaledWidth/Height?

Comment: no,i need to change the width and height,then how to do it?